# SearchBar problem while trying to search Firestore and reload the tableview

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, uisearchbar

I have a tableView and I use infinite scroll to populate firestore data with batches. Also I have a searched bar and I am trying to query firestore with the text from the text bar and then populate it in the tableview. I have 3 main problems.

1. When I click search thee first time I get an empty array and an empty tableview, but when I click search the second time everything seems fine.
2. When I finally populate the searched content I want to stop fetching new content while I am scrolling.
3. If I text a wrong word and press search then I get the previous search and then the "No Ingredients found" printed twice.

This is my code for searchBar:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard let text = searchBar.text else {return}
        searchIngredients(text: text)
        self.searchBarIngredient.endEditing(true)
        print("\(searchIngredients(text: text))")
    }
```

The code for function when I click search

```
func searchIngredients(text: String) -> Array<Any>{

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("Ingredients").whereField("compName", arrayContains: text).getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("\(err.localizedDescription)")
                print("Test Error")
            } else {
                if (querySnapshot!.isEmpty == false){
                    self.searchedIngredientsArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({Ingredients(dictionary: $0.data())})

                }else{
                    print("No Ingredients found")
                }
            }
        }

         self.tableView.reloadData()
         ingredientsArray = searchedIngredientsArray

        return ingredientsArray

    }
```

Finally the code for scrolling

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let off = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let off1 = scrollView.contentSize.height

        if off > off1 - scrollView.frame.height * leadingScreensForBatching{
            if !fetchMoreIngredients && !reachEnd{
                beginBatchFetch()
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't write the beginBatchFetch() cause its working fine and I don't think is relevant.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your question is that Firestore is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56296280/firebase-datadescription-returns-empty-array/56297185#56297185).

It takes time for Firestore to return documents you've requested and that data will only be valid within the closure calling the function. The code outside the closure will execute way before the data is available within the closure.

So here's what's going on.

```
func searchIngredients(text: String) -> Array<Any>{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("Ingredients").whereField("compName", arrayContains: text).getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, err) in
        //the data has returned from firebase and is valid
    }
    //the code below here will execute *before* the code in the above closure
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    ingredientsArray = searchedIngredientsArray
    return ingredientsArray
}
```

what's happening is the tableView is being refreshed before there's any data in the array.

You're also returning the ingredientsArray before it's populated. More importantly, attempting to return a value from an asynchronous function can (and should) generally be avoided.

The fix is to handle the data within the closure

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
   var ingredientArray = [String]()
   func searchIngredients(text: String) {
         let db = Firestore.firestore()
         db.collection("Ingredients").whereField("compName", arrayContains: text).getDocuments{ (querySnapshot, err) in
             //the data has returned from firebase and is valid
             //populate the class var array with data from firebase
             //    self.ingredientArray.append(some string)
             //refresh the tableview
         }
     }
```

Note that the searchIngredients function should not return a value - nor does it need to

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You made me understand a lot and it worked. The problem now is that it prints "No Ingredients found" two times.

Comment: @NickStefanidis Well, it's possible the function is being called twice, or perhaps the print statement is inside a loop. The function works for me and only print's it once. Perhaps asking another question with your updated code and a snippet of your Firestore structure would help.

Comment: Thank you. It was my mistake. One more thing. I have infinite scroll. Is it possible to stop fetching when I have the founded cells; there will more than 1 because I have synonyms.

Comment: @NickStefanidis Generally, if you want infinite scroll, you will be paginating your data so your app would, for example, load 10 rows at a time, then as the user scrolls it would load the next 10 etc. There's some great info in the Firestore Guide on [Paginating Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

Comment: i paginate my data successfully that's not the problem. But when I search something and reload the tableView with the data that have been found , the pagination starts again after I scroll. It's not possible to disable the scrolling because data may be more than the screen height.

Comment: @NickStefanidis That sounds like we should take a look at your code. Perhaps opening a separate question, since it's a different question, would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did that :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56458956/how-to-stop-firestore-pagination-when-searched-data-are-loaded-in-tableview