# Error setting root view controller with SWReveal in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swrevealviewcontroller

I[m trying to set the root view controller in the app delegate based in a condition. When the app starts and set the root view controller a controller that has code to reveal the rear ViewController this error: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

App Delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var docRef: DocumentReference!
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if user != nil{
            var userId = user?.email
            docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("user/\(userId!)")
            docRef.getDocument(completion: { (docSnapshot, error) in
                guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}
                let data = docSnapshot.data()
                variables.userType = data!["tipo"] as? String ?? ""
            })

            if variables.userType == "doctor" {
                let consulta = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConsultaController")
                self.window?.rootViewController = consulta
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            } else if variables.userType == "paciente"{

            }
        } else {
            let consulta = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConsultaController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = consulta
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

code in the view controller where the error is triggered.

EDIT: error is triggered when the initial view controller is loaded. The initial view controller is determined by condition in the app delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpSWReveal()
}

func setUpSWReveal(){
    menuBtn.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()) //error triggered here
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
}
```

Comment: Could  you be more specific where the error is triggered? It's best practice to add a breakpoint to  you code and step through line by line, examining the variables to determine when they are not what you expect them to be or watching for crash. Also `return true` is going to execute long before the variables var is populated.

Comment: error is triggered when the initial view controller is loaded.

Comment: Ok. There are a few issues with that code. Most importantly, this code `if variables.userType == "doctor" {` will execute *before* variables.userType is assigned within the Firestore closure. Code is faster than the internet and data returned from Firestore is ONLY valid within the closure following the Firestore call. Check out my answer here [Firestore is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442492/searchbar-problem-while-trying-to-search-firestore-and-reload-the-tableview/56446914#56446914)

Comment: Oh. and why are you returning true from `addStateDidChangeListener`? It doesn't use a boolean return.

Comment: its returnig true from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Thanks to everyone, i fixed it by setting the front and rear view controller in every case.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't looking at the code correctly due to formatting. If fixed the formatting and yes, return true is correctly placed. HOWEVER, it will return true before the rest of the code executes so that could be a future issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the front and rear view controller in each condition. im using a navigation controller so some parts of the code below are properties of a navigarion controller

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var docRef: DocumentReference!
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil{
            var userId = user?.email
            docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("user/\(userId!)")
            docRef.getDocument(completion: { (docSnapshot, error) in
                guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}

                let data = docSnapshot.data()
                variables.userType = data!["tipo"] as? String ?? ""
                if variables.userType == "paciente" {
                    let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
                    let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
                    var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

                    let front = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "MedicionViewContoller") as! MedicionVC
                    let rear = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuController") as! MenuVC

                    frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: front)
                    frontNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 12.0/255.0, green: 73.0/255.0, blue: 120.0/255.0 , alpha: 1.0)
                    frontNavigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 45)!
                    ]
                    frontNavigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
                    revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
                    revealController.rearViewController = rear
                    revealController.delegate = self
                    mainRevealController  = revealController

                    UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window??.rootViewController = mainRevealController
                    //
                }
                else {
                    let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
                    let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
                    var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

                    let front = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "ConsultaController") as! ConsultaVC
                    let rear = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuController") as! MenuVC

                    frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: front)
                    frontNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 12.0/255.0, green: 73.0/255.0, blue: 120.0/255.0 , alpha: 1.0)
                    frontNavigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 45)!
                    ]
                    frontNavigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
                    revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
                    revealController.rearViewController = rear
                    revealController.delegate = self
                    mainRevealController  = revealController

                    UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window??.rootViewController = mainRevealController
                }
            })
        }else{
            let login = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = login
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    return true
}
```